# WPF Adding Submenu item programmatically with telerik RadMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

Basically what I am trying to do is loop through an array and add those array items as submenu items in a telerik:RadMenu

I looked at the examples given by telerk, but the example that applies has an ambiguity problem between the name of one of the classes (MenuItem) and a system control of the same name.

If anyone could give a short example of how to do this it would be greatly appreciated.

menu hierarchy example:

```
MainItem (staticly coded)
   subitem1
   subitem2
   subitem3
```

(all subitems would be added from the array)

Comment: Use a fully qualified typename for the Telerik class.

Comment: Tried that.. Didn't work. - Suffice to say that the example given in the telerik documentation doesn't work at all, at least as far as I can tell.  That's why I'm asking for assistance.

Comment: Oh, you said there's an ambiguity problem stopping you from following their example... but there isn't. So I'd remove that and state what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <telerik:RadMenu VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="Menu" Height="400">
        <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Item 1">
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="SubItem 1" />
            <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="SubItem 2" />
        </telerik:RadMenuItem>
        <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Item 2" />
    </telerik:RadMenu>

    <Button Content="Add submenu" Height="20" Width="200" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

CodeBehind:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var subMenuItemToAdd = new RadMenuItem();
        subMenuItemToAdd.Header = "Sub Menu Item";

        var secondMenuItem = Menu.Items[1] as RadMenuItem;
        secondMenuItem.Items.Add(subMenuItemToAdd);
    }
```

I created one button and inside the click event handler, it will add sub menu items to second menu item.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Tim - If this answer helped you, please mark it as answered.

Comment: How to do that if you also create the main menu programmatically?